# how to get sub categories by parent category id in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

please, can any one help me , I am new in wordpress world.
***how to get sub categories by parent category id in wordpress?***

Comment: So you want to find all the terms of a taxonomy whose parent is $id?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `get_terms($taxonomies, $args);`

```
$parent_term_id = 4; // term id of parent term (edited missing semi colon)

$taxonomies = array( 
    'category',
);

$args = array(
    'parent'         => $parent_term_id,
    // 'child_of'      => $parent_term_id, 
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```

You could also use `'child_of'` instead;

> Note: the difference between child_of and parent is that where parent only gets direct children of the parent term (ie: 1 level down), child_of gets all descendants (as many levels as are available)

Codex: [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Answer (score 8):

Here is the Simplest way to get child category from specific parent

```
$parent_id = 12;
$termchildren = get_terms('product_cat',array('child_of' => $parent_id));
```